# Validating a radio button and checkbox in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

## Overview

In my view I have two `radio_button` form helpers: `Yes` and `No`

I also have one `check_box` with the identifier `:agreement`

Here is my code:

```
%h6 Is this a membership?   

= f.radio_button :agreement, true, id: "membership_yes" 

= f.label :agreement, "Yes", value: true

= f.radio_button :agreement, false, id: "membership_no" 

= f.label :agreement, "No", value: false

%br/ 

= f.check_box :agreement, type: "checkbox", id: "agreement-box"
= f.label :agreement, label: "I acknowledge that I have completed at least 8 workouts for the month."
```

## What I want to accomplish

In my rails model I would like to perform validations on the `:agreement` checkbox.

If `Yes` is selected then show the checkbox and make it required. If `No` is selected then hide the checkbox and make it not required.

I would greatly appreciate any help or resources that would point me in the right direction.

## What I have tried

I have tried giving the radio buttons and checkbox `id`'s while using Jquery to hide, show, and set the `required` property of the checkbox to `false` or `true`.

I could only show and hide the checkbox. When setting the `required` property to `true` or `false` it was ignored and the form submitted no matter what when I pressed the `Submit` button

If there are any better ways to organize my code I would appreciate the suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what for do you use `radio_button` if you use boolean value? Just use `check_box`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, add an attribute accessor for the radio buttons in the model.

```
attr_accessor :show_agreement
```

Change your form,

```
%h6 Is this a membership?   

= f.radio_button :show_agreement, true, id: "membership_yes", name: "agreement_radio_buttons" 

= f.label :show_agreement, "Yes", value: true

= f.radio_button :show_agreement, false, id: "membership_no", name: "agreement_radio_buttons" 

= f.label :show_agreement, "No", value: false

%br/

#agreement-box
   = f.check_box :agreement, type: "checkbox"
   = f.label :agreement, label: "I acknowledge that I have completed at least 8 workouts for the month."
```

Show/hide checkbox on radio button change,

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input[name$='agreement_radio_button']").click(function() {
        var showCheckBox = $(this).val();
        if (showCheckBox) {
            $("#agreement-box").show();
        } else {
            $("#agreement-box").hide();
            $("#agreement-box input").prop('checked', false);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Last but not least, add validations in your model,

```
validates :agreement, acceptance: {accept: true}, if: :needs_agreement_acceptance?

private

def needs_agreement_acceptance?
    show_agreement
end
```

I haven't tested it, but I guess you will be fine. 
Also, make sure to show or hide the agreement-box when (re)loading the page, depending on the preselection of the radio buttons.

**About not letting the form to submit**

You can disable the submit button, and check when checkbox for changes. When it's true, remove the disable attr.

```
$('#agreement_box').on('change', 'input', function() {
    if (self.is(":checked")) {
        $('#submit-btn').removeAttr('disabled')
    } else {
        ...
    }
});
```

*Sorry for not being more thorough*

Comment: When trying to submit the form, rails gives me an error saying that `Undefined method 'needs_agreement_acceptance?'` Also I should not even be able to submit the form if `Yes` is selected and the checkbox is not.  Thank you for your help though! I would appreciate any additional input as I have been struggling with this for a long time now.

Comment: Check for typos, I don't see anything wrong with that. (for reference: [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless) ).